# Auditing asp.net authentication

Tags: asp.net, authentication, logging, azure-active-directory

I have an ASP web api service and I want to log all the authentication request
I am using WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication for authentication
What is the best way to do it?
I checked the answer as suggested:
[The definitive guide to form-based website authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549/the-definitive-guide-to-form-based-website-authentication) but there is no log example or which classes to use,  only the fact that you should do it, so code sample would be appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The definitive guide to form-based website authentication](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/549/the-definitive-guide-to-form-based-website-authentication)

Comment: How about asking Google ? or browse github